# Как правильно разместить такие стрелки?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

Как расположить эти стрелки правильно? Желательно чтоб до 720px они не сильно сползали, если это сложно реализовать, то хотя бы чтоб до 992px было все ок.[image]

Comment: Talk is cheap. Show me the code. Без кода не очень ясно (очень не ясно) в чём проблема. Правила СО говорят о необходимости предоставить минимальный код для воспроизведения проблемы. Кода нет. Ответить сложно (невозможно).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну вот как-то так. **Только CSS!**

```css
#wrp {
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.wrp__img {
  width: 220px;
}

.wrp__img img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 200px;
}

.wrp__right .wrp__img,
.wrp__right .wrp__img img {
  float: right;
}

.wrp__left .wrp__img,
.wrp__left .wrp__img img {
  float: left;
}

#arrow__wrp__right,
#arrow__wrp__left {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 40px;
  height: 60px;
}

#arrow__wrp__right {
  right: 150px;
}

#arrow__wrp__left {
  left: 150px;
}

#arrow__wrp__right div,
#arrow__wrp__left div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px dashed steelblue;
}

#arrow__wrp__right.arrow div,
#arrow__wrp__left.arrow div {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent steelblue;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#arrow__right,
#arrow__left {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 300px 0 0 300px;
}

#arrow__right:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 41px;
  left: 36px;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  border-top: 2px solid steelblue;
  border-right: 2px solid steelblue;
}

#arrow__right:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 35px;
  left: 42px;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border: 2px solid steelblue;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#arrow__left:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 40px;
  left: 38px;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid steelblue;
  border-right: 2px solid steelblue;
}

#arrow__left:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 38px;
  left: 40px;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border: 2px solid steelblue;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

h2 {
  color: steelblue;
  font-weight: bold;
}

p {
  color: darkslategray;
}

.wrp__right h2,
.wrp__right p {
  text-align: left;
}

.wrp__left h2,
.wrp__left p {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrp" class="wrp__right">
  <div class="wrp__img"><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/644328118229012480/wzQ9Y12I_400x400.jpg"></div>
  <div class="wrp__text">
    <h2>Кошка со своенравным характером</h2>
    <p>Кошка — это существо со своенравным гордым характером и очень отзывчивое на ласку хозяина. Котята очень быстро привязываются к человеку и активно с ним играют.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="arrow__wrp__right" class="arrow">
    <div id="arrow__right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="wrp" class="wrp__left">
  <div class="wrp__img"><img src="https://cache3.youla.io/files/images/780_780/58/1a/581a340086302ec926b91a62.jpg"></div>
  <div class="wrp__text">
    <h2>Кошка</h2>
    <p>Кошка — это существо со своенравным гордым характером и очень отзывчивое на ласку хозяина. Котята очень быстро привязываются к человеку и активно с ним играют.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="arrow__wrp__left" class="arrow">
    <div id="arrow__left"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Если это делать на SVG то ни каких проблем не будет , я покажу то что я не доделал так как во времени ограничен

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

svg {
  padding: 0 30px;
}

text {
  white-space: pre-wrap
}

.b2 {
  transform: translateY(200px);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 640 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip">
      <circle cx="570" cy="140" r="70" fill="blue" />
    </clipPath> 
    
  <clipPath id="clip2">
    <circle cx="70" cy="140" r="70" fill="blue" />
  </clipPath> 
    
    <g id="arrow">
    <path d="M170,70 Q280,0  390,70" 
          fill="none"
          stroke="red"
          stroke-width="2"
          stroke-dasharray="4 4"/>

    <circle cx="400" cy="75" r="4" 
            fill="none"
            stroke="red"
            stroke-width="2"/>

    <path d="M178,75 170,70 174,59" fill="none" stroke="red"
          stroke-width="2" />
    </g>
  </defs>

<g>
  <image xlink:href="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/225396/0fa14049-dc70-47ad-93c2-f6b0f46f43f5/s1200"
         x="500" y="70"
         width="150"
         height="150"
         rx="200"
         preserveAspectRatio="none"
         clip-path="url(#clip)"/>
  <use href="#arrow" x="80"/>
  <text x="0" y="80" font-size="20" fill="lightblue">
    Оставляет ваш салон 
    свободным
  </text>
    <text x="0" y="130" font-size="12">
Автомобильное сидение не предназначено
для маленьких детей. Оно не безопасно 
при столкновении, так как штатные ремни
в машине не рассчитаны на маленький рост
пассажира. В связи с этим были внесены.
  </text>
</g>
<!---->
  
<g  class="b2">
  <image xlink:href="https://2.allegroimg.com/original/03f3be/af53f6ed471987d8c1e34046d962"
         x="0" y="70"
         width="150"
         height="150"
         rx="200"
         preserveAspectRatio="none"
         clip-path="url(#clip2)"/>
  
  <use href="#arrow" x="-20"/>
  <text x="400" y="80" font-size="20" fill="lightblue">
    Оставляет ваш салон 
    свободным
  </text>
    <text x="400" y="130" font-size="12">
Категория 0 (до 10 кг) имеет второе название
«автолюлька»,так как сделано в виде люльки
коляски. На практике используется до 
возраста 6 месяцев. Главный плюс – 
горизонтальное положение. Обязательно 
для перевозки недоношенных и слабых детей 
  </text>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен насколько это верно, но заметил что все стрелки выше остальных блоков, фото и текста.
Я бы юзал flex css:
Создаю 2 блока по вертикали со 100% шириной, тип - flex
В первом блоке создаю блок с изображением(стрелкой) и размещаю посредине

```
justify-content:center
```

Во втором два блока - контейнер фото и контейнер текста.
В зависимости от ширины страницы - flex элементы должны вести себя синхронно, так что сьезжать ничего не должно