# Как правильно сверстать секцию на CSS?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как правильно сверстать эту секцию на CSS ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может сделать пункты в виде изображений, а текст как обычно?

Comment: А как сделать стрелки между блоками?

Comment: сделать фотку для одной стрелочки, а потом разместить её в трех разных местах

Comment: 4 блока позишен релетив, а картинку пнг/свг позишн абсолют выровнять как на фото

Comment: Во-первых, а зачем на css, почему бы не взять svg? Во-вторых, требуется ли какая-нибудь резиновость-адаптивность?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-то подобное как-то уже было в вопросе [Как правильно разместить такие стрелки?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1076445/377637)

Вот пример реализации вашей задачи:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 50px 20px 0 20px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 100%;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: cadetblue;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px dotted cadetblue;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent cadetblue;
}

.arrow_top {
  top: -5px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.arrow_bottom {
  top: 20px;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.arrow:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  border-top: 1px solid cadetblue;
  border-right: 1px solid cadetblue;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 50%, cadetblue 50%);
}

.arrow:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid cadetblue;
  border-right: 1px solid cadetblue;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 50%, cadetblue 50%);
}
```

```html
<div>1<div class="arrow arrow_top"></div></div>
<div>2<div class="arrow arrow_bottom"></div></div>
<div>3<div class="arrow arrow_top"></div></div>
<div>4</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, друг!!!

Comment: Привет! Почему, я всё так у тебя написал, а стрелки ровные или не появляются? Непоняно)

Comment: Стрелки как положено, а линия прямая ---------- ?

Comment: всё есть, спасибо! мне просто практика надо, локально на ноуте. А можно линии сделать как-то адаптивность?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы делал все списком. Для начала сверстать все без пунктирных линий. Главному блоку ul дать свойства:

```
ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap; /* если при адаптации блоки должны переходить на новую строку */
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

А уже каждому дочернему блоку:

```
ul > li {
    margin-top: /* чтобы на маленьких экранах между вертикальными блоками сверху и снизу было расстояние */
    padding: /* мин. расстояние между блоками справа и слева, чтобы не слипались по горизонтали */
    /* ... */
}
```

Изображения внутри ободков делать через background, так как они декоративные, а не контентные.

Далее для добавления пунктирных линий я бы воспользовался псевдоэлементами:

```
ul > li::after {
    content: "";
    background: url(svg картинка линии);
    background-size: 200px 50px;
    background-position:
}
```

Еще можно transform: translate() воспользоваться, если background-position не сработает.

Как можно заметить, положение четных и нечетных линий разное, поэтому можно не давать им классы, а воспользоваться псевдоклассами:

```
ul > li::after:nth-child(even/odd)
```

P.S. Дополните и отредактируйте мой ответ, пожалуйста, желательно профессионалы