# Как сверстать эту секцию адаптивно?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 50px 20px 0 20px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 100%;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: cadetblue;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px dotted cadetblue;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent cadetblue;
}

.arrow_top {
  top: -5px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.arrow_bottom {
  top: 20px;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.arrow:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  border-top: 1px solid cadetblue;
  border-right: 1px solid cadetblue;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 50%, cadetblue 50%);
}

.arrow:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid cadetblue;
  border-right: 1px solid cadetblue;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 50%, cadetblue 50%);
}
```

```html
<div>1<div class="arrow arrow_top"></div></div>
<div>2<div class="arrow arrow_bottom"></div></div>
<div>3<div class="arrow arrow_top"></div></div>
<div>4</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы добиться адаптивности всей нашей конструкции, один из вариантов - это использовать относительную единицу (проценты, %), которая будет рассчитываться исходя из свойств родительского элемента. Пример:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 4%;
}

.circle,
.arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(25% - 40px);
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: calc(25% - 40px);
  margin: 0 16px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px dotted cadetblue;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent cadetblue;
}

.arrow_top {
  top: -25%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.arrow_bottom {
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.arrow:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  width: 7%;
  height: 7%;
  border-top: 1px solid cadetblue;
  border-right: 1px solid cadetblue;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 50%, cadetblue 50%);
}

.arrow:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  width: 7%;
  height: 7%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid cadetblue;
  border-right: 1px solid cadetblue;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 50%, cadetblue 50%);
}

.circle span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 2vw);
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4vw;
  color: cadetblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle"><span>1</span>
    <div class="arrow arrow_top"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle"><span>2</span>
    <div class="arrow arrow_bottom"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle"><span>3</span>
    <div class="arrow arrow_top"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle"><span>4</span></div>
</div>
```

Связанный вопрос: [Как правильно сверстать секцию на CSS?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1231946/377637)

Comment: Вам like, спасибо за всё!